# How does Angular handle binding for [class.example]="true"?

Tags: angular

There are these special template bindings that you can do with CSS classes and styles.

They look something like this:

```
<div [class.example]="true"
     [style.width.px]="100">
</div>
```

I took a look at the `ngClass` and `ngStyle` directives, but couldn't figure out how they work.

I was wondering if I can use this kind of syntax with my own bindings for my components.

For example:

```
<my-component [name.first]="John" [name.last]="Smith></my-component>
```

With the code like this:

```
@Component({..})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    public name: any;
}
```

I was hoping angular would pass something like `{first:"John",last:"Smith"}` to the `name` input, but I just get an error saying that the `name.first` and `name.last` inputs don't exist on the component.

Is there a way to get the above to work like the `[class.any-thing-here]` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These bindings are kind of special cases `BoundElementPropertyAst`
**[Live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/RYKruuyQIKJZ6rscp55w/)**

```
PropertyBindingType.Class
PropertyBindingType.Style
```

Angular parses it in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.x/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/binding_parser.ts#L244-L298

**binding_parser.ts**

```
const ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX = 'attr';
const CLASS_PREFIX = 'class';
const STYLE_PREFIX = 'style';

createElementPropertyAst(elementSelector: string, boundProp: BoundProperty):
    BoundElementPropertyAst {
  if (boundProp.isAnimation) {
    return new BoundElementPropertyAst(
        boundProp.name, PropertyBindingType.Animation, SecurityContext.NONE, boundProp.expression,
        null, boundProp.sourceSpan);
  }

  let unit: string|null = null;
  let bindingType: PropertyBindingType = undefined !;
  let boundPropertyName: string|null = null;
  const parts = boundProp.name.split(PROPERTY_PARTS_SEPARATOR);
  let securityContexts: SecurityContext[] = undefined !;

  // Check check for special cases (prefix style, attr, class)
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    if (parts[0] == ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX) {
      boundPropertyName = parts[1];
      this._validatePropertyOrAttributeName(boundPropertyName, boundProp.sourceSpan, true);
      securityContexts = calcPossibleSecurityContexts(
          this._schemaRegistry, elementSelector, boundPropertyName, true);

      const nsSeparatorIdx = boundPropertyName.indexOf(':');
      if (nsSeparatorIdx > -1) {
        const ns = boundPropertyName.substring(0, nsSeparatorIdx);
        const name = boundPropertyName.substring(nsSeparatorIdx + 1);
        boundPropertyName = mergeNsAndName(ns, name);
      }

      bindingType = PropertyBindingType.Attribute;
    } else if (parts[0] == CLASS_PREFIX) {
      boundPropertyName = parts[1];
      bindingType = PropertyBindingType.Class;
      securityContexts = [SecurityContext.NONE];
    } else if (parts[0] == STYLE_PREFIX) {
      unit = parts.length > 2 ? parts[2] : null;
      boundPropertyName = parts[1];
      bindingType = PropertyBindingType.Style;
      securityContexts = [SecurityContext.STYLE];
    }
  }

  // If not a special case, use the full property name
  if (boundPropertyName === null) {
    boundPropertyName = this._schemaRegistry.getMappedPropName(boundProp.name);
    securityContexts = calcPossibleSecurityContexts(
        this._schemaRegistry, elementSelector, boundPropertyName, false);
    bindingType = PropertyBindingType.Property;
    this._validatePropertyOrAttributeName(boundPropertyName, boundProp.sourceSpan, false);
  }

  return new BoundElementPropertyAst(
      boundPropertyName, bindingType, securityContexts[0], boundProp.expression, unit,
      boundProp.sourceSpan);
}
```

They have no connection with any of `@Input`s of build-in directives. They are just bindings for elements.

When angular creates view it uses these bindings to apply to element

```
return jit_viewDef1(0,[(_l()(),jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'div',[],[[2,'example',
      null],[4,'width','px']],null,null,null,null)),(_l()(),jit_textDef3(null,['\n'])),
      (_l()(),jit_textDef3(null,['\n']))],null,function(_ck,_v) {
    var currVal_0 = true;
    var currVal_1 = 100;
    _ck(_v,0,0,currVal_0,currVal_1);
});
```

Look at `elementDef` above. This function takes bindings params:

```
function elementDef(................................bindings...
                                                       \/
jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'div',[],[[2,'example', null],4,'width','px']]
```

`[class.any-thing-here]` binding doesn't do what you want. `ngClass` and `ngStyle` do it. But if you take a look at their implementation

```
[ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}"
[ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}"
```

you can notice that there is no magic here. They can take an object.

So angular respects `[attr.x]` `[class.x]` `[style.x]` but won't work with `[name.x]` since will expect `name.x` property [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YUn0rT1cmhJDt3VsfgqM?p=preview) (see console)

Comment: This would be a cool feature. I hope that make it usable by people in a later version.